# Continuity at a point versus continuity after algebraic manipulation

Tags: functions, continuity

Let's say that I have a function that isn't defined at $x = 0$, such as:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}.
$$
In fact, the only real numbers it's defined on is $[-1,1] \setminus \{0\}$, so I'll take that to be the domain. This function is not defined at $x = 0$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about continuity or discontinuity at $x = 0$. However, if I multiply by the quantity $\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}$, then
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}} = \frac{x^2}{x(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} = \frac{x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}. 
$$
I end up with a function that is not only defined at $x = 0$, but continuous at $x = 0$, so I can easily take its limit as $x \to 0$ by just "plugging in $0$." As far as I can tell, this expression is still "equal" to $f(x)$ since all I did was multiply by $1$, but in some way by multiplying by this convenient conjugate, I've gained continuity at the point $0$; in fact, the function is now defined at all real numbers, which also is quite confusing to me.

My question is: how exactly should I think about this or even give a name to it? Is this resulting expression still "equal" to $f(x)$? Is it even the same function? Have I in some way "extended" the function to a continuous function?

Comment: This is called a removable discontinuity. It amounts to the existence of a continuous extension to $0$.

Comment: You have some sign errors in your algebra. Every square root should have a minus sign, not a plus sign. This also means that the end result is still only defined on [-1,1] and not for all real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, what you've done is known as "function extension." By multiplying your original function by a specific expression, you've created a new function that is continuous and defined at points where the original was not, notably at $x=0$. This new function is not strictly "equal" to your original function but is an extension of it, maintaining the original values over their common domain. This process highlights how altering the domain and form of a function can yield a function with different properties and a broader scope of application.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. If I could just ask: is the reason the limit is unchanged as $x \to 0$ because the function itself and its continuous extension agree on an opening neighborhood of $0$, and that's all that really matters for a limit? I assume that, when doing the algebraic manipulation of multiplying by the conjugate, it only makes sense to take $x$ in the domain of $f$. Is that right?

Comment: @BradG. Yes, you're right. The limit as $x→0$ is unchanged because the function and its continuous extension agree near x=0. For limits, the behavior around the point, not the value at the point, is key. When multiplying by the conjugate, you use 
x values within the original function's domain to ensure valid manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a physicist but I think your function is only "not defined at $0$" if you try to evaluate it numerically and naively when you quite obviously hit a division by zero.

In that respect it is no different to $sinc(x) = sin(x)/x$ (apart from that function having a value of $1$ at $0$).

Your formula mathematically still has a perfectly well defined analytic value in the limit as $x -> 0$

If you consider the function in the limit $x -> 0$ and take the Taylor expansion of the sqrt it becomes clear that the function **is** well defined at $0$ it is just that you cannot use the original formula numerically.

$$ f(x) = \frac {1 - \sqrt {1-x^2}} x \.$$

Expand the numerator sqrt leading term in $x^2$ and then we have $\lim x - > 0$

$$ f(x) = \frac{1 - 1 + \frac{x^2} 2 + ...} x  = \frac x 2 \.$$

The multiply trick is one of the classic ways to avoid catastrophic numerical cancellation in such cases and is algebraically equivalent to the original function but much more accurate to compute numerically.

You can contrast that behaviour with the much more pathological function

$$ g(x) = \sin{ \frac 1 x } \.$$

Which is very badly behaved both numerically and analytically as it approaches 0.

Comment: Do not confuse the value of a function at a point with the limit of that function at that point. The OP's function is indeed not defined at $0$, but it may be extended to a continuous function around that point.